# Detecting inconsistency in a set of non-strict inequalities

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, inequality, inequalities

Given a set of variables and a set of strict inequalities, it's straightforward enough to detect whether there is an inconsistency: make a directed graph whose nodes are variables; for each assertion `a > b` add an edge from `a` to `b` and vice versa for `a < b`; check whether there are any cycles in the graph.

However, this does not suffice for non-strict inequalities; the above algorithm doesn't handle the case where you have some assertions `a = b`.

What's the simplest algorithm to detect inconsistency in a set of non-strict inequalities?

Comment: Do you mean `a=b` or `a≤b` ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust `a=b`.

Comment: Equalities can be seen as creating aliases. You can preprocess to cluster the variables by union-find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way works:

1. Replace every `x=y` with `x>=y` and `y>=x`
2. Create a directed graph among the variables with, with a green edge from `x` to `y` if `x>=y`, and a red edge from `x` to `y` if `x>y`
3. Determine the strongly connected components of the graph, using e.g., [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm)
4. If there is a red edge within any SCC, then the set of equations is inconsistent.

The way this works is simple:  In any cycle of `>=` edges, all the variables must be equal, but that's not possible if one of those edges requires that they are not equal.